# Изменение формы с помощью <select>

Tags: form, select

С помощью чего можно сделать так, чтобы при выборе варианта из тега `<select>`, под ним появлялось необходимое поле?

Например, я в `<select>` выбираю вариант FURNITURE и под Switcher'ом сразу появляются поля `Height`, `Width`, `Length`. Остальные (`Size`, `Weigth`) должны быть скрыты.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте етот код!
(написан на jquery)

```
$( "select" ).blur(function() {
  switch($("select").val()){
     case "login":
        $("#login_input").show();
        $("#password_input").hide();
     break;

     case "password":
        $("#login_input").hide();
        $("#password_input").show();
     break;
  }
});
```